# HTTP cookie manager not working in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have placed cookie manager above  the thread group.I have extracted cookie value from sampler request(request1) using regex extractor.I have placed cookie manager with extracted cookie values under the sampler(request2).
When i replayed the script the cookie is not set for request2.It shows no cookies.
NOTE:
When I removed the cookie manager placed above the thread group I am getting errors in samplers.

I have placed cookie manager above  the thread group.I have extracted cookie value from sampler request(request1) using regex extractor.I have placed cookie manager with extracted cookie values under the sampler(request2).
When i replayed the script the cookie is not set for request2.It shows no cookies.
NOTE:
When I removed the cookie manager placed above the thread group I am getting errors in samplers.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Cookie Manager handles incoming cookies **automatically**, it:

1. Extracts the cookies from the [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) response header
2. On subsequent requests if domain and path of the request matches the ones of the cookie(s) the cookie is being added to the request's [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header

So there is no need to use any post processors for extracting the cookies.

If the cookie manager is "not working" most probably there is a problem with the cookie, i.e. it's expired or domain of the request is different or something like this. If you want to see what's going on under the hood you can [increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for the cookie manager by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control" level="debug" />
```

if there are issues with cookies and JMeter is unwilling to add the cookie you can force it by

1. Choosing less restrictive policy, i.e. `netscape`

   [image]
2. Adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   CookieManager.check.cookies=false
   ```

More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)